# heapify prolog implementation

Tags: prolog, heap

I'm testing my heapify in prolog but it doesn't work as i expected. In particular it miss some elements i think and it doesn't generate a correct heap.

```
min_heapify(H, P) :- heap_has_size(H, S), P = S, !.

min_heapify(H, P) :-
    R is (2*P)+1,
    heap_has_size(H, S), R =< S,
    heap_entry(H, P, K1, _V1),
    heap_entry(H, R, K2, _V2),
    K1 =< K2, !.

min_heapify(H, P) :-
    L is 2*P,
    heap_has_size(H, S), L =< S, 
    heap_entry(H, P, K1, V1),
    heap_entry(H, L, K2, V2),
    K1 > K2,
    retract(heap_entry(H, P, K1, V1)),
    retract(heap_entry(H, L, K2, V2)),
    assert(heap_entry(H, P, K2, V2)),
    assert(heap_entry(H, L, K1, V1)),
    min_heapify(H, L).
```

Comment: It seems that you never swap a father node with a right child node...

Comment: Besides, when a father node has two children nodes, it must be swapped with the smaller child node.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, as I said before in my comment, you never swap a father with a right child.

See your code altered so that it can show you what it is doing at each step (I just included a predicate to show how the heap is modified during the execution).

I think that will help you to understand the problem with your implementation).

**Hint**: predicate `heapify` must adjust the heap entries from bottom to top, not from top to bottom (i.e., starting from entry `Size//2` and decreasing until entry `1`).

```
:- dynamic heap_entry/4.

min_heapify(H, P) :-
    format('~nHeapify node: ~w~n', [P]),
    show_tree(H),
    get0(_),
    fail.

min_heapify(H, P) :-
    heap_has_size(H, S),
    P = S,
    !.

min_heapify(H, P) :-
    R is (2*P)+1,
    heap_has_size(H, S), R =< S,
    heap_entry(H, P, K1, _V1),
    heap_entry(H, R, K2, _V2),
    K1 =< K2, !.

min_heapify(H, P) :-
    L is 2*P,
    heap_has_size(H, S), L =< S,
    heap_entry(H, P, K1, V1),
    heap_entry(H, L, K2, V2),
    K1 > K2,
    retract(heap_entry(H, P, K1, V1)),
    retract(heap_entry(H, L, K2, V2)),
    assert(heap_entry(H, P, K2, V2)),
    assert(heap_entry(H, L, K1, V1)),
    min_heapify(H, L).

heap_has_size(H, S) :-
    aggregate_all(count, heap_entry(H,_,_,_), S).

show_tree(H) :-
    heap_has_size(H, S),
    show_tree(H, S, 1, 0).

show_tree(H, S, I, D) :-
    (   I =< S
    ->  R is 2*I + 1,
        L is 2*I,
        show_tree(H, S, R, D+1),
        heap_entry(H, I, K, V),
        tab(5*D),
        writeln([K,V]),
        show_tree(H, S, L, D+1)
    ;   true ).


:- initialization
    retractall(heap_entry(_,_,_,_)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  1, 16, a)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  2,  2, b)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  3,  4, c)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  4,  3, d)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  5,  7, e)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  6, 10, f)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  7,  9, g)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  8,  8, h)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  9, 14, i)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1, 10,  1, l)).
```

Here is the result:

```
?- min_heapify(h1,1).

Heapify node: 1
          [9,g]
     [4,c]
          [10,f]
[16,a]
          [7,e]
               [1,l]
     [2,b]
               [14,i]
          [3,d]
               [8,h]
|: 

Heapify node: 2
          [9,g]
     [4,c]
          [10,f]
[2,b]
          [7,e]
               [1,l]
     [16,a]
               [14,i]
          [3,d]
               [8,h]
|: 

Heapify node: 4
          [9,g]
     [4,c]
          [10,f]
[2,b]
          [7,e]
               [1,l]
     [3,d]
               [14,i]
          [16,a]
               [8,h]
|: 

Heapify node: 8
          [9,g]
     [4,c]
          [10,f]
[2,b]
          [7,e]
               [1,l]
     [3,d]
               [14,i]
          [8,h]
               [16,a]
|: 
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of `min_heapify`, according to the hint that I gave you before (you can compare it with your implementation and see what you have to modify):

```
:- dynamic heap_entry/4.

min_heapify(H) :-
    heap_has_size(H, S),
    N is S//2,
    min_heapify_loop(H, S, N).

min_heapify_loop(H, S, N) :-
    (   N < 1
    ->  true
    ;   sift_down(H, S, N),
        succ(M, N),
        min_heapify_loop(H, S, M) ).

heap_has_size(H, S) :-
    aggregate_all(count, heap_entry(H,_,_,_), S).

sift_down(H, S, I) :-
    (   has_smaller_child(H, S, I, J)
    ->  swap_entries(H, I, J),
        sift_down(H, S, J)
    ;   true ).

has_smaller_child(H, S, I, J) :-
    2*I =< S,
    J1 is 2*I,
    J2 is 2*I + 1,
    entry_key(H, I,  K0),
    entry_key(H, J1, K1),
    entry_key(H, J2, K2),
    (   K1 < K2
    ->  (J, K) = (J1, K1)
    ;   (J, K) = (J2, K2) ),
    K < K0.

entry_key(H, I, K) :-
    (   heap_entry(H, I, K, _)
    ->  true
    ;   K = +inf ).

swap_entries(H, I, J) :-
    retract(heap_entry(H, I, K1, V1)),
    retract(heap_entry(H, J, K2, V2)),
    assertz(heap_entry(H, I, K2, V2)),
    assertz(heap_entry(H, J, K1, V1)).

show_tree(Heap) :-
    heap_has_size(Heap, Size),
    show_tree(Heap, Size, 1, 0).

show_tree(Heap, Size, Root, Depth) :-
    (   Root =< Size
    ->  RightChild is 2*Root + 1,
        LeftChild is 2*Root,
        show_tree(Heap, Size, RightChild, Depth+1),
        heap_entry(Heap, Root, Key, Value),
        tab(5*Depth),
        writeln([Key, Value]),
        show_tree(Heap, Size, LeftChild, Depth+1)
    ;   true ).

:- initialization
    retractall(heap_entry(_,_,_,_)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  1, 16, a)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  2,  2, b)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  3,  4, c)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  4,  3, d)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  5,  7, e)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  6, 10, f)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  7,  9, g)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  8,  8, h)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1,  9, 14, i)),
    assertz(heap_entry(h1, 10,  1, l)),
    writeln('\nBefore heapify\n'),
    show_tree(h1),
    min_heapify(h1),
    writeln('\nAfter heapify\n'),
    show_tree(h1).
```

Execution result:

```
Before heapify

          [9,g]
     [4,c]
          [10,f]
[16,a]
          [7,e]
               [1,l]
     [2,b]
               [14,i]
          [3,d]
               [8,h]

After heapify

          [9,g]
     [4,c]
          [10,f]
[1,l]
          [7,e]
               [16,a]
     [2,b]
               [14,i]
          [3,d]
               [8,h]
```